# How to overwrite a file that is altering an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, io

I'm writing a program in order to keep track of DVDs in my library. I'm having trouble altering the text file that saves an added or removed DVD object from the arraylist. Whenever I call my save method, which is the one that overwrites the existing text file holding all the information, it will not change it whatsoever. My add and remove methods work fine but it's just the save method which overwrites the file that I'm reading from that will not work. The following code is what I was attempting to use to save the arraylist to the file. My filename is DVDCollection.txt and the boolean variable flag is a static variable used to check whether or not the code which adds or removes an object from the arraylist was reached.

```
public void save() {
    try{
        if(flag=true){
            FileWriter instream = new FileWriter("DVDCollection.txt",false);
            instream.close();
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("The file could not be written to!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you write to the file?

Comment: Do you have any code that actually tries to write to the file?  Currently you just have a file writer that is instantly closed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why this method should save an array list, as the actual code that writes to this file is missing. Here is simple test, let's start here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileSaveTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSaveTest test = new FileSaveTest();
        test.fill();
        test.save();
    }

    public void fill() {
        arrayList.add("My disc 1");
        arrayList.add("My disc 2");
        arrayList.add("Another disc");
    }

    public void save() {
        try {
            if(flag) { // you dont need ==true
                FileWriter instream = new FileWriter("DVDCollection.txt",false);
                for (String entry : arrayList) {
                    instream.write(entry + "\n");
                }
                instream.close();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("The file could not be written to!");
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static boolean flag = true;
}
```

Next, it's not very good, to close the file in such manner. If an exception occurs while writing, the file will not be closed. instream.close() should be put into the "finally" block. This block will be executed in any case, regardless of whether an exception occurred or the return keyword met:

```
public void save() {
    Writer instream = null;
    try {
        if(flag) { // you dont need ==true
            instream = new FileWriter("DVDCollection.txt",false);
            for (String entry : arrayList) {
                instream.write(entry + "\n");
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("The file could not be written to!");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (instream != null)
                instream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception during close");
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using java 7, you can use try-with-resources syntax:

```
public void save() {
    if(flag) { // you dont need ==true
        try (Writer instream = new FileWriter("DVDCollection.txt",false)) {
            for (String entry : arrayList)
                instream.write(entry + "\n");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("The file could not be written to!");
        }
    } // you dont need "return  else { return; }" anymore
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 or above it's as simple as:

```
    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("first line", "second line");
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("my-file.txt"), lines);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception
    }
```

Make sure you provide the right path!